# Angular 2 error using model in component

Tags: angular, components

I am learning Angular 2 and I am getting a strange error:

> ERROR in [default] /home/szabo/PhpstormProjects/recipe-book/src/app/recipes/recipe-list/recipe-item.component.ts:11:2 
>       Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
>         Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Here is my "model":

**recipe.ts**

```
export class Recipe {
    constructor(public name, public description, public imagePath) {

    }
}
```

Here is my **RecipeItemComponent**:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

import { Recipe } from '../recipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-recipe-item',
    templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input recipe: Recipe; //line 11
  recipeId: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your model isn't the problem here, you are missing `()` on `@Input` decorator:

```
@Input() recipe: Recipe;
```

Read more about `Input` [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#bindings).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I am new to Angular and I thought at that as a simple annotation, not necessarily a function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I believed is something serious, but that - how I missed that? :) How did you saw it? I am new with Angular 2.

Comment: @Adrian Mistakes happen all the time, don't worry. I suggest that you complete official Angular 2 tutorial, it will help you a lot to understand concepts of Angular 2 and it will help you with the syntax so you won't make silly mistakes like this anymore. :-) Here's the link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/